# Excluding out of stock products in shortcode [products or product_category] WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

The thing I want to accomplish is the following. In WooCommerce 3.9,
Whenever I use the shortcode [product_category category="jeans"] or any other category 
I want it to show products of this category **except** the products which are out of stock

I know I can change the setting to hide all out of stock product in WooCommerce, but I want them to be shown at all places (archive, shop, widgets) except when I use the shortcode

I've tried codes like the one below (which i assume only works for [products category="jeans"] ) So that would also be an option

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shortcode_products_query' , 'tryout_exclude_oos_shortcodes');

function tryout_exclude_oos_shortcodes($query_args){

    $query_args['tax_query'] =  array(array( 
        'taxonomy' => 'product_visibility',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'   => array('outofstock'),
        'compare' => 'NOT IN',  
        )); 

    return $query_args;
}
```

At this moment I tried a lot, but my knowledge doesn't is limited at the moment.
Is what I'm asking even possible and so.. what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shortcode_products_query', function( $query_args, $atts, $loop_name ){
    if( $loop_name == 'product_category' ){
        $query_args['meta_query'] = array( array(
            'key'     => '_stock_status',
            'value'   => 'outofstock',
            'compare' => 'NOT LIKE',
        ) );
    }
    return $query_args;
    }, 10, 3);
```

You can change the loop name to fit your application. Code goes in your child theme functions.php.